# Get element in list with numeric name

Tags: r

That's probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere...

Anyways, here's my simple problem. I am loading a yaml file in R with users metadata. After parsing the yaml with `yaml::yaml.load_file`, the list looks like this:

```
$users
$users$`1`
$users$`1`$user
[1] "Alice"


$users$`2`
$users$`2`$user
[1] "Bob"
```

I can get the user with id = 1 by:

```
user_list$users$`1`$user
```

That returns:

```
[1] "Alice"
```

My question is: how can I transform a numeric 1 into this "quoted" version, so I can pass the id as a function argument that retrieves the user I want?

Comment: You can't use `$` with variables-in-function-arguments regardless of whether they are numeric or not. Use `[[` to do extraction with variables. `x = 2`, then `user_list$users[[as.character(x)]]$user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$`, use `[[`

```
id <- 1
user_list$users[[as.character(id)]]$user
```